# Dictionaries define past participle as a noun

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english

Why do dictionaries define past participle as a noun[C]?
For example in https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/past-participle

Comment: The past participle itself is a noun. What else would it be?

Comment: @IanMacDonald 
I think it's a form of a verb. It's used as a verb in the passive voice and sometimes used as an adjective.

Comment: I think Ian MacDonald meant "Past participle" is a noun. A past participle is a form of a verb.

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary is, rightly, saying that the *word* "participle" is a noun, and the phrase "past participle" is a noun phrase, meaning a part of speech, the form of a verb ... used in some grammatical structures such as the passive and the present perfect. The *word* "verb" is a noun as well, meaning a word or phrase that describes an action, condition, or experience. "Adverb", "pronoun", "conjunction" and "preposition" are all nouns, as are "paragraph" and "sentence".

Comment: Thanks a lot! Got it. I've another question. Is there any difference between using past participle as a verb or adjective. I think we can consider it an adjective in the passive voice, too.

Comment: @AliZahy The whole point of the name "participle" is that it designates forms which may act as both a verb AND another wordclass at the same time -- it "participates" in both categories of use.